# Keycloak User Role Mapping and Pemissions

Tags: keycloak

How can I write and apply policy to have only single role at a time to user in keycloak and User can only assign the roles to other users based on the policies? I have seen that in the latest version of keycloak, they removed the support of map-role fine-grained policies. Could you please let me know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Create role based policies by selecting only one role. Associate that policy with a resource when creating permissions.

For more information refer to [keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_policy_overview)